# Create aggregated object for a batched REST call in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to upload a bunch objects to a REST API and I want to aggregate them into batches when I send them in JSON. Unfortunately, the batch object needs to be in a specific JSON format, and I'm having difficulty creating the correct Data Flow in ADF.

The data looks something like this:

| CustomerId | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | USA |
| 2 | Bob | CAN |
| 3 | Charlie | MEX |

For examples sake, I need the data in batches of 2, and when making the REST API call, the JSON data should looks like this:

Batch 1

```
{
  "customers" : [
    {
     "name" : "Alice",
     "country" : "USA"
    },
    {
     "name" : "Bob",
     "country" : "CAN"
    }]
}
```

Batch 2

```
{
  "customers" : [
    {
     "name" : "Charlie",
     "country" : "MEX"
    }]
}
```

Can someone help me understand how to write a Data Flow that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a dataflow like [this example Data flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA2Pr.png).

**Steps:**

1. Create a sample source data. ([example source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvR7D.png))
2. Create derivedColumn as below ([example derived column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1fRU.png)):

```
column_value_1: it’s used to generate rownumber
test: It’s used to create a JSON data like:
{
     "name" : "Alice",
     "country" : "USA"
}
```

3. Create a window activity to generate a `rowNumber` column.
   [example window Sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vlCZ.png), [example window column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRcN2.png)
4. Aggregate configuration for Group By uses the expression below. ([example Aggregate Group By](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0tmB.png))

```
toInteger(divide(rowNumber,2))`
```

5. Aggregate configuration for Aggregates uses the expression below. This is used to generate the JSON of customers ([example Aggregate Aggregates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLKIa.png))

```
collect(test)
```

6. Exclude unnecessary columns and remove the mapping of Group. [(example sink config)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/960Id.png)

**Results**
The REST API server side will receive the body like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zdbE.png)